# Object mapping with a defined schema Angular 2/4

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-directives, object-object-mapping

I am in a situation where i have to design an object mapper with a defined schema ie I will get a response with an array of objects which is the schema for object mapping like this.

```
[
{
"fieldToMap":"entityName",
"fieldName":"name"
},
{
"fieldToMap":"entityNumber",
"fieldName":"number"
}
]
```

When i hit any api endpoint and get the response like this,

```
[
{
"name":"something",
"number":"something"
},
{
"name":"something",
"number":"something"
}
]
```

I have to map it to an object and create a nw object like this

```
[
{
"entityName":"something",
 "entityNumber":"something"
},
{
"entityName":"something",
 "entityNumber":"something"
}
]
```

How to go about solving this ? Is it good way to loop through the response and replace the keys of the response with the keys presented in the schema or is there any other method which can be used?Any help would be appreciated.Thank you

Comment: can you share code what you are tried in this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this

```js
var schema = [
    {
        "fieldToMap":"entityName",
        "fieldName":"name"
    },
    {
        "fieldToMap":"entityNumber",
        "fieldName":"number"
    }
]

var response = [
    {
        "name":"something",
        "number":"something"
    },
    {
        "name":"something",
        "number":"something"
    }
];

var result = mapObject(response, schema);

function mapObject(data, schema) {
    return data.map(function(el) {
        var obj = {};
        schema.forEach(function(s) {
            obj[s.fieldToMap] = el[s.fieldName];
        });
        return obj
    })
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm.Thank you..let me know if you have any improvisation in mind :)]

Comment: Just a follow up question if its not too much to ask for.If the response has additional keys other than the schema,is there any way to copy them into the result as wel ?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
getAll() {
    return this.http.get('sample.json')
        .map(res => <SchemaModel[]>res.json());
}
```

Comment: Doesnt answer the question as i cannot have a hard-coded schema